# Full url rewrite including www.example.com

Tags: url-rewriting

What I want to do is to make a link that in the browser looks like this:
`http://www.showedlink.com/media/page.html` but in the back it points to `http://www.mywebsite/com/media/demo/page.html`
I want to know if it's possible to do a full url rewrite like that.
PS: the user must see this `http://www.showedlink.com/media/page.html` link when it's on the page.

Thanks!!